# How to assign list of teams to a list of users randomly in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, random

For example:

| Team | User |
| --- | --- |
| USA | Mark |
| England | Sean |
| India | Sri |

assigning users to different teams randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shuffle` to shuffle a user list;

```
from random import shuffle
teams = ['USA', 'England', 'India']
users = ['Mark', 'Sean', 'Sri']
shuffle(users)
print([(t,u) for t,u in zip(teams, users)])
```

To assign multiple teams to a player, you can use `iter()` to ensure there are no duplicates

```
from random import shuffle
teams = ['USA', 'England', 'India','France', 'Brazil', 'Australia']
users = ['Mark', 'Sean', 'Sri']
shuffle(teams)
teams_iter = iter(teams)
print([(u,(t1,t2)) for u,t1,t2 in zip(users, teams_iter, teams_iter )])
```

Comment: Cool thank you so much for the quick reply , just one more question: how to assign two teams from a list of teams to each users from a list of users without having any duplicate teams, I mean unique teams for a user.

Comment: Sri - USA, INDIA ,    Mark - Brazil, France   , Seb - Germany, Australia

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include this too.

Answer (score 1):

In random module use choice

```
from random import choice
choice(['USA','England','India'])
'India'
```

For a dataframe of users you could use lambda to get a random choice for each user:

```
df.apply (lambda x: choice(['USA','England','India']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a posible solution

```js
from random import randrange

User = ['Mark', 'Sean', 'Sri']
Team = ['USA', 'England', 'India']
_range = len(User)

new_list  = []

while len(new_list) != _range:
  try:
    rr = randrange( len(Team) );
    new_list.append( [Team.pop(), User.pop( rr ) ] )
  except:
    ""

print(new_list)
```